# MySQL performance with multiple Counts

Tags: php, mysql

Is it faster to have multiple `MySQL Count` instances in one query or separate queries for each count instance? And If so how would I combine these two queries?

```
 $msd_call_qry = "SELECT count(event) AS MissedCalls  FROM queuelogdb.queue_log WHERE (agent = '$agent_name[0]' OR agent = '$agent_name[1]')"
                . " AND (event = 'ABANDON' OR event = 'RINGNOANSWER') AND queuename IN ('500','505') AND time BETWEEN '$lastDay' AND '$today'";

 $ttl_call_qry = "SELECT count(event) AS TotalCalls from queuelogdb.queue_log WHERE (agent = '$agent_name[0]' OR agent = '$agent_name[1]') "
                . "AND event = 'CONNECT' AND queuename IN ('500','505') AND time BETWEEN '$lastDay' AND '$today'";
```

Comment: You should probably use one query with group by on `event` columnd and sum it later in php if needed. But this heavily depends on how your data looks like and what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is the same.  Most of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause are the same.  So, you should be able to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(event = 'ABANDON' OR event = 'RINGNOANSWER') AS MissedCalls,
       SUM(event = 'CONNECT') AS TotalCalls
FROM queuelogdb.queue_log
WHERE agent IN ('$agent_name[0]', '$agent_name[1]') AND
      queuename IN ('500', '505') AND
      time BETWEEN '$lastDay' AND '$today'". ";
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed.